Complex $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A^TA=0$?
Can we find a non trivial complex 3x3 matrix $A$ such that $A^TA=0$?
If I decompose $A$ as $B +iC$, with $B$ and $C$ real, I get 18 parameters with 18 equations corresponding to
$B^TB=C^TC$ and $B^TC=-C^TB$,
but I don't know if there is a solution or if the problem is impossible. Of course $A$ should be singular but can it be rank 2?
If a solution exists, what is the name of such as property?

@Dietrich that  does give zero trace  but $A^T A$  is not the zero matrix

Well, I think this matrix does not satisfy $A^TA=0$

Sorry, I misread  trace zero. Still, it is possible without much computation.

No problem. I guess that the matrix can only be of rank 1 from Sylvester inequality.

for 2 by 2 take
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rr}
x & y \
ix & iy \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Isn't the zero matrix a complex matrix? Couldn't this answer the question?

You're right but I meant a non trivial matrix. I've updated my question. However, I think the general answer is below.

From the $2\times 2$ case one can easily construct $3\times 3$-matrices $A$ with $A^TA=0$, namely
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \cr ix & iy & iz \cr 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thanks. And it also corresponds to a specific case of what I wrote below.

From Sylvester rank inequality $2 \cdot{\rm rank} A \leq {\rm rank} A^TA + 3$ so $A$ can only be rank $1$. Posing $A=uv^T$, we see that $A^TA=0$ if either $u^Tu=0$ or $v^Tv=0$.

The title question asked for a concrete example of a $3\times 3$-matrix.

you're right. Too bad we can't propose two solutions. I reassigned yours as it indeed gives a concrete example.
